# Same Constructor Name Error

Tags: java, oop, constructor

Okay so I'm trying to make more than one constructor with the same name. I'm getting an error and I am not sure why.I'm basically trying to make it so that when a player inputs their name, it will still work even if they don't input a specific field such as a suffix, etc. I'm aware I still have to add the setters and getters later and all that but I'm just trying to get the constructors set up right now. Any idea as to why it is giving me an error?

```
public class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String middleInitial;
    private String lastName;
    private String suffix;


    public String playerName(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName, String suffix){

        this.firstName = firstName; 
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        return suffix + firstName + middleInitial + lastName;
    }

    public String playerName(String firstName, String lastName){

        this.firstName = firstName; 
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        return suffix + firstName + middleInitial + lastName;
    }

    public String playerName(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName){ //this is where the error is. "Duplicate method playerName (String String String) in type Name"

        this.firstName = firstName; 
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        return suffix + firstName + middleInitial + lastName;
    }

    public String playerName(String firstName, String lastName, String suffix){//same error here

        this.firstName = firstName; 
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        return suffix + firstName + middleInitial + lastName;
    }
```

Comment: The method signatures are the same... the methods are the exact same... what do you have 3 methods that do the same thing?

Comment: And the methods are not constructors.

Comment: The content inside them is just to get them set up, I will change that later. I'm just trying to figure out why it's giving me an error when the arguments are different for all of them. Also, please don't give me a hard time. I'm new to this and still learning.

Comment: @Zero the arguments aren't different

Comment: So Imust be confused then.

Comment: your two last methods signature are equals

Comment: To my understanding, I have the first one with arguments firstName, middleInitial, lastName, and suffix.

the second one: firstName, lastName
third one: firstName, middleInitial, lastName
fourth one: firstName, lastName, suffix

Comment: Types, not variable names!

Answer (score 1):

If you were to call

```
obj.playerName ("string1", "string2", "string3");
```

how would java know whether this was

```
public String playerName(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName)
```

or

```
public String playerName(String firstName, String lastName, String suffix)
```

Comment: I thought that Java was able to recognize constructor overloading?

Comment: How about you Mr Zero, can you please tell me which method I am meaning to call?

Comment: When you call playerName(), depending on the arguments that you pass it, Java should be able to successfully choose which method it is that should be used right?

Comment: Yes, so in my answer, I am passing three Strings - which method do I want?

Comment: Has the penny dropped yet?

Comment: Ya, I got it now thanks. I asked a new question in a reply to an answer given on this thread if you wanna help with that too..

Comment: Just call `playerName(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName, String suffix)` with null values e.g. `playerName ("Joe", "A" "Zero", null);` or  `playerName ("Joe", null, null, "Sir");`

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the constructor where you have the error

```
public String playerName(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName) { /* error */ }
```

Now this is another one where you have the same error

```
public String playerName(String firstName, String lastName, String suffix){ /* same error */ }
```

That is because your are using same **DATA TYPE** for the arguments in both of them and same number of arguments. So here java won't be able to decide which one to call when you use one of these.
I hope this is clear for you now...

Comment: Ohhh okayy... Alright this makes sense. Thank you! So quick question. How would I set up my code so that when a player types in their firstName, middleInitial, and lastName it distinguishes that from firstName, lastName, and suffix in another method? Like how would I set up my code so that it could choose between the right method?

Answer (score 0):

When overloading methods (or constructors), you can only have methods that differ in their type signatures. Thus, only one method (of the same name) that takes three `String` parameters. However, you currently have no constructors. What I think you really wanted was to create `Name` instances, perhaps to also have getters and setters and finally to override `toString` (so you can get the `Name` as a `String`). Something like,

```
public class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String middleInitial = "";
    private String lastName;
    private String suffix = "";

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName) {
        this(firstName, lastName);
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String middleInitial, String lastName, 
                String suffix) {
        this(firstName, lastName, middleInitial);
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleInitial() {
        return middleInitial;
    }

    public void setMiddleInitial(String middleInitial) {
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(firstName);
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        if (middleInitial.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(middleInitial).append(' ');
        }
        sb.append(lastName);
        if (suffix.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(' ');
            sb.append(suffix);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The example `toString` is performing `String` concatenation, and you could do the less efficient

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = firstName;
    if (str.length() > 0) {
        str += " "; // <-- str = str + " ";
    }
    if (middleInitial.length() > 0) {
        str += middleInitial + " ";
    }
    str += lastName;
    if (suffix.length() > 0) {
        str += " " + suffix;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah that makes more sense. However, this is an assignment for class and I haven't learned what StringBuilder does nor append. Therefore, I'm not allowed to use that in my code. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you so much!